# Pywinrm and HTTPS Connection

Tags: python, https

does anyone know how to create HTTPS connection using pywinrm to Windows server? 
I tried it on my own, however I am unable to establish the connection.

Steps I have done so far:

1. Installed and imported pywinrm
   `pip install pywinrm`
2. Generated certificate and key: `openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -keyout key.pem -out server.pem`
3. Converted server.pem to server.cer `openssl x509 -inform PEM -in server.pem -outform DER -out server.cer`
4. Installed `server.cer` on target Windows server (inside '*Trusted Root Cert. Auth*')

**Notes:**

- The WinRM service works over the HTTPS, which has been tested from another machine based on Windows using a different certificate
- I am using macOS Mojave, Python 3.7.6

And now, I am unable to establish winrm connection, the script

```
import winrm

destination = 'https://10.0.0.1:5986'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
cert_pem = 'crt-temp/server.pem'
cert_key_pem = 'crt-temp/key.pem'

session = winrm.Session(destination, 
                        auth=(username, password), 
                        transport='certificate', 
                        cert_pem=cert_pem, 
                        cert_key_pem=cert_key_pem)
result = session.run_ps('hostname')
print(result.std_out)
```

and the error I receive:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.0.0.1', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError( 1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))

**How to troubleshoot this?**

Using: https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm

Comment: Partialy solved using `session = winrm.Session(destination, auth=(username, password), transport='ntlm')`

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with self signed certificate where the signing Certificate Authority is not considered as a trusted one. You could either skip the server certificate validation or add the CA certificate to trusted Certificate Authorities on the client machine.

**Skipping certificate validation**

```
import winrm

destination = 'https://10.0.0.1:5986'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
cert_pem = 'crt-temp/server.pem'
cert_key_pem = 'crt-temp/key.pem'

session = winrm.Session(destination, 
                        auth=(username, password), 
                        transport='certificate', 
                        cert_pem=cert_pem, 
                        cert_key_pem=cert_key_pem,
                        # Skip validation below
                        server_cert_validation='ignore'
    )

result = session.run_ps('hostname')
print(result.std_out)
```

**Adding CA certificate to trusted Certificate authorities**

```
# For CentOS/RHEL
mv yourselfsignedcacert.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
update-ca-trust
```